# unable to backup chef server 12 ( HA )

Tags: centos, chef-infra, backup, knife

I am trying to backup data that includes sql data using:
(as root )

```
# knife ec backup backup_8_27_6AM --with-user-sql --with-key-sql -c /etc/opscode/pivotal.rb
```

but getting error:

```
ERROR: Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf 
entry for host "::1", user "opscode_chef", database "opscode_chef", SSL off
```

the knife ec backup command works without the sql qualifiers.
Did anyone come across the same issue, and share how they resolved it?

here is the how /var/opt/opscode/drbd/data/postgresql_9.2/pg_hba.conf is configured:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          ME
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         opscode-pgsql                               peer

host    all         opscode-pgsql         samehost           md5

host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0           md5
```

Comment: Does `chef-server-ctl backup` work?

Comment: @coderanger
backup qualifier is not available in this case, so i am using knife ec backup.
but just to give you a sample of other commands not working:
[root@chef ~]# chef-server-ctl user-list
ERROR: OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError: header too long
[root@chef ~]# chef-server-ctl org-list
ERROR: OpenSSL::X509::CertificateError: header too long

Comment: Well that's a new error. Anything unusual about your TLS configuration?

Comment: Also FWIW have you contacted Chef Software support? The HA backend is a commercial product so you get a support contract with it.

Comment: I was able to do a backup , will post update soon